# Importing/Exporting child component error in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I just simply want to export and import a child component into my rot-directory (App.js) and render it out in the browser, but I get this error message in terminal "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'". I don't understand what I typed wrong or why I cannot import my child to my App.js.

Have tried to solve this problem but with no results. I've been testing this in my "App.js" to get a more explicit name but not working:

```
import { ContactsList } from './ContactsList';
```

I've also tried typing this in my "ContactsList.js" but with no result:

```
export default class ContactsList extends React.Component {}
```

I'am a beginner so excuse me for my knowledge but I really want to learn this and the power of react. Please help me for better understanding!

--------App.js---------

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ContactsList from './ContactsList';


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Contacts List</h1>
                <ContactsList />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

--------ContactsList.js---------

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ContactsList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>Joe 555 555 5555</li>
                <li>Marv 555 555 5555</li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
export default ContactsList;
```

--------webpack.config.js---------

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/App.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test:/\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ContactsList.js file, use a `<div>` to wrap the `<ul>`

Also in your webpack config file. Can you try to use *loader : "babel-loader"* instead of *loader: 'babel'*(Don't forget to install the babel-loader package)

Also remove the query part and try to create a separate .babelrc file with the following settings:

```
{
    "presets" : [
        "react",
        "es2015"
    ]
}
```

Hope this can solve your problem

Comment: ok. should I place the "presets" inside the "module:" but outside from the "loaders:" then?

Comment: No, just remove the query and presets part. Create a file named '.babelrc' at the same level of webpack config file. And then put: {
    "presets" : [
        "react",
        "es2015"
    ]
} in that .babelrc file

Answer (score 0):

> According to es6 module mechanism the default module should be
>   imported without {}

```
import ContactsList  from './ContactsList';
```

> and export like

```
export default class ContactsList extends React.Component {}
```

> But I guess you are trying babel on .jsx extension however it seams
>   you are using ContactsList.js
>
> Just change the  to .jsx to .js in

--webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/App.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test:/\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

> Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes on webpack.config.js file. first replace

```
    test:/\.jsx?$/,
```

with

```
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
```

Secondly import modules as follows

```
import ContactsList  from 'path-of-the-file';
```

But you need to provide the actual path. to get the path correct there are many plugins available depending on the text editors we use. i am using https://github.com/sagold/FuzzyFilePath